# Como calcular promedio movil 12 meses anteriores

Tags: powerbi, dax

Como estan?
Como muestro en la imagen, en la primera columna tengo el dato por mes, con la siguiente dax:

LASTNONBLANKVALUE(VW_Reporte_Balance_Diario[Fecha].[Date],CALCULATE(
SUM(VW_Reporte_Balance_Diario[Saldo corregido]), D_Agrupador_Cuenta[Nivel 1] = "PATRIMONIO NETO")) / 1000000

lo que necesito es mostrar en una segundo columna, el promedio de los 12 meses anteriores a cada mes con el dato. Intenté varias formas pero sin dar una solución aun, me ayudarían?

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! Agrega lo que intentaste y no funciono, asi te explican porque no funciono...